# MPI joining vectors

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to do some parallel calculations and then reduce them to one vector.

I try it by dividing for loop into parts which should be calculated separatedly from vector. Later I'd like to join all those subvectors into one main vector by replacing parts of it with values gotten from processes. Needless to say, I have no idea how to do it and my tries were in vain.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(A, n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(b, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(x0, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("My id: %d, mySize: %d, myStart: %d, myEnd: %d", rank, size, mystart, myend);
while(delta > granica)
{
    ii++;
    delta = 0;
    //if(rank > 0)
    //{
        for(i = mystart; i < myend; i++)
        {
            xNowe[i] = b[i];
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(i != j)
                {
                    xNowe[i] -= A[i][j] * x0[j];
                }
            }
            xNowe[i] = xNowe[i] / A[i][i];
            printf("Result in iteration %d: %d", i, xNowe[i]);
        }
        MPI_Reduce(xNowe, xNowe,n,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to ignore your calculations and assume they're all doing whatever it is you want them to do and at the end, you have an array called `xNowe` that has the results for your rank somewhere within it (in some subarray).

You have two options.

**The first way uses an `MPI_REDUCE`** in the way you're currently doing it.

What needs to happen is that you should probably set all of the values that do not pertain to your rank to 0, then you can just do a big `MPI_REDUCE` (as you're already doing), where each process contributes its `xNowe` array which will look something like this (depending on the input/rank/etc.):

```
rank:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
value:   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0
```

When you do the reduction (with `MPI_SUM` as the op), you'll get an array (on rank 0) that has each value filled in with the value contributed by each rank.

**The second way uses an `MPI_GATHER`.** Some might consider this to be the "more proper" way.

For this version, instead of using `MPI_REDUCE` to get the result, you only send the data that was calculated on your rank. You wouldn't have one large array. So your code would look something like this:

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(A, n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(b, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(x0, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("My id: %d, mySize: %d, myStart: %d, myEnd: %d", rank, size, mystart, myend);
while(delta > granica)
{
    ii++;
    delta = 0;

    for(i = mystart; i < myend; i++)
    {
        xNowe[i-mystart] = b[i];
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(i != j)
            {
                xNowe[i] -= A[i][j] * x0[j];
            }
        }
        xNowe[i-mystart] = xNowe[i-mystart] / A[i][i];
        printf("Result in iteration %d: %d", i, xNowe[i-mystart]);
    }
}
MPI_Gather(xNowe, myend-mystart, MPI_DOUBLE, result, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

You would obviously need to create a new array on rank 0 that is called `result` to hold the resulting values.

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by Hristo in the comments below, `MPI_GATHER` might not work here if `myend - mystart` is not the same on all ranks. If that's the case, you'd need to use `MPI_GATHERV` which allows you to specify a different size for each rank.

Comment: So if I want to do it the easiest way, I basically need to set values other than the ones I want to 0 and sum it like I have done. Well I've got one more question, my MPI_Reduce throws such an error (any idea what is wrong?): Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce: Invalid buffer pointer, error stack:
MPI_Reduce(sbuf=0x045EC150, rbuf=0x045EC150, count=1000, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, ro
ot=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
Buffer parameters sendbuf and recvbuf must not be aliased

Comment: You are using the same buffer for both your sending and receiving buffer (that's what the last bit "sendbuf and recvbuf must not be aliased" means). If you want to do that, you need to use the `MPI_IN_PLACE` option for the sending buffer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but got one more problem, when trying to run it on 2 processes:  [ranks] message

[0] terminated

[1] fatal error
Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce: Invalid buffer pointer, error stack:
MPI_Reduce(sbuf=MPI_IN_PLACE, rbuf=0x0496E118, count=1000, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM,
root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
sendbuf cannot be MPI_IN_PLACE

Comment: After short search it seems I can't use MPI_IN_PLACE, since only root can use it. I'll try to make a temporary variable for holding the value.

Comment: You can just have an if statement that tests to see if you're root before your `MPI_REDUCE`. If you're root, use `MPI_IN_PLACE`. Otherwise, pass in NULL as the recvbuf argument since it doesn't matter what is in there for non-root processes.

Comment: Using `MPI_Gather` is not "more proper" - it is **the proper** way to do the task :) Also, since the OP haven't shown that `myend-mystart` is equal in all processes, `MPI_Gatherv` might more appropriate.

Comment: Very true @HristoIliev. Though I had a feeling that he'd choose door #1. :)

Comment: Using replicated data is often easier as it mimics shared-memory programming. But then inevitably comes the moment when one has to gather the results.